# How to import key words are areas latex reports from a list of values

Tags: automation, key-value

I write long test reports. And generally i have a spreadsheet (xls) with all the relevant data regarding the tests.

I would like to automatically include that data from excel throughout the report.

Is there a package that is capable of doing this?

i.e. currently;

```
...
\newcommand{\testNumber}{001}
\newcommand{\vehicle}{Volkswagen Beetle}

\begin{document}
During test number TR-\testNumber a \vehicle was subject to etc....
\end{document}
...
```

desired;

I want to export a csv (or anything) from excel containing the hundreds of values used throughout the reports.

```
<content of keyval.csv>
Key, Value
testNumber, 001
vehicle, Volkswagen Beetle
```

and import those values for use in the report. So some attempted code that doesn't work;

```
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\csvloop{file={keyval.csv}, head to column names, command=%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname \Key
    \endcsname{\Value}
}

\begin{document}
During test number TR-\testNumber a \vehicle was subject to etc....
\end{document}
```

The above code compiles but gives blanks for results.

Alternatively if you know/think there is a better way to automate the generation of a report please let me know.

Comment: Yes there are. `datatool`, `pgfplotstable`, `csvsimple` etc. Which one to use depends on your applications. All of them do a quiet good job. Start with `datatool`.

Comment: Thanks, however I have been trying to sort this out for months and quite seriously for a few days with no luck. I can't find a solution that doesn't involve creating a table or a mail merge for multiple documents.